# How to add django-guardian permisions after object was created in CreateView in django?

Tags: django, django-models, permissions, django-class-based-views, django-guardian

I got simple CreateView that is using basic ModelForm and I want to add `can_view` permission for current user for this specific object after it's created . As I understand it must be done after saving object. Should I use `post_save` signals for this? Keep in mind I don't want to trigger this when modifying existing object.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in the model save method

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        if 'pk' not in self:
            #add you permission code here
        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

What this does is checks if your object has a primary key.  If it doesn't, then this is a new object and the permissions should be created.  If there *is* a primary key, then this object is being edited and no permissions should be added.

Comment: I fought about that but in model i don't have acces to request.user. So i would need to  think about some workaraund to get the user that's creating the object

Comment: Tried that and I got `argument of type 'ModelName' is not iterable` on the line with`if 'pk' not in self:`

Comment: I dont know why but `if 'pk' not in self.__dict__ ` works. But as i previously wrote `ObjectNotPersisted: Object firn lastn needs to be persisted first`

Comment: @ Lord_JABA, checking if is there can be done in three ways. the best is if if hasattr(self, "pk"). will return true if the attribute exists. however it does not tell you if the value of this attribute is None (i.e. will return true if pk is None. The second is if self.pk: will evaluate to true if pk has a value, but this will throw an error if pk does not exist i.e. pk not yet created. Calling pk in self.__dict__ is essentially the same as option 1.